# Cant vertically stack elements inside a div

Tags: html

I am trying to get my formatting to look like the following:

```
Question                          Choice
textarea                          textarea
```

The HTML I have formats it like this:

```
Question textarea                  Choice textarea
```

How can I get two separate columns of element, but then line those elements up inside of their respective columns vertically?

```
<div id="container1" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="width: 600px; float: left;">
        <div style="display: inline-block">
            <label for="">Question</label>
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="">Choice</label>
        <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's because you are using the `<label>` tag. Try just with a `<p>` tag. Something like this

```
<div id="container1" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
<div style="width: 600px; float: left;">
    <div style="display: inline-block">
        <p>Question</p>
        <p><textarea></textarea></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Choice</p>
    <p><textarea></textarea></p>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked, buy that seems like an incredible hack.  Why should I surround every element with a paragraph tag just to vertically stack them?

Comment: I believe the `<label>` tag puts the label beside the element that it is labeling. `<p>` tags by default stacks the content just like you would a paragraph in a word document.

Comment: Got it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use labels a simple `<br>` will do the trick.

```
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="width: 600px; float: left;">
    <label for="">Left Question</label>
    <br />
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 620px;">
      <label for="">Right Question</label>
      <br />
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```